# User specific database entries

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do user and group specific database entries in my Django-REST-Framework backend. I am conceptually lost. Here's the idea I have so far:

On the database objects I want to retrieve, add a group attribute as well as a creator attribute. When I query the database, depending on the situation, I will filter by `creator=request.user` or `group=request.user.groups.all()`.

However I do know that the above group part doesn't work. And I imagine I could loop through every group the user belongs to and check the group against each one. However this (to me) seems like a conceptually terrible idea. Lets say the user belongs to 20 groups and the database has 100000 entries - that's up to 2 million checks for one retrieval. That can't be okay. So my question is - how should I do this type of by group retrieval?

Comment: One simple question, in your model, 'group' should be a ManytoMany field, right?

Comment: It's just a ForeignKey - I only want one group to have access to the database entries.

Comment: well, if that is true, I was confused by your 'request.user.groups.all()', since that will return a list (queryset) of instance. did you try 'in' statement in Django queryset API? I mean it is hard to give advice without code. This is best guess I would have.